# creating multidimensional array of objects in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a three dimensional array of class objects in Matlab. I have defined my class using `classdef` and now I want to use Matlab arrays to create arrays and access and modify the data I have created in the objects.

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        MyPropertiy1
        MyPropertiy2
    end

    methods
        function a = func1(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

Now I want to have something like this:

```
mc = MyClass[2][3][5];
mc [1][2][2] = MyClass(param);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've written it, except using [MATLAB's indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) instead of Python's:

```
mc(2, 3, 5) = MyClass;
mc(1, 2, 2) = MyClass(param);
```

Note that, as written, your class can't accept any input arguments, so `MyClass(param)` is going to throw an error.